# Display values of a list table in eloquent using laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1

I have this table with 4 id's related to other tables.

Table List:

```
  id   table1_id    table2_id table3_id   table4_id
  1    2             3        2           1
  2    1             4        3           3
```

I want now to output the values related to that table's ids

```
  id   table1_name    table2_name  table3_name    table4_name
  1    jay            student       singer        actor
  2    jeane           teacher      drummer       actress
```

ListController:

```
     public function index()
{   
   $res = ListModel::with('table1','table2','table3','table4')->get();

    $foreach($res as r){

       return $r->table1_name;
    }

   return view('list.index',compact('res'));
}
```

My problem here is that the output will be null instead of jay.How can I display now the values?Please help..

list table

```
    public function up()
{
    Schema::create('list_table', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('table1_id');
        $table->string('table2_id');
        $table->string('table3_id');
        $table->string('table4_id');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

//additional info

Table1 Model

```
 public function list(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\ListModel');
}
```

List Model

```
 public function table1(){
    return $this->hasMany("App\Table1",'id','table1_id');
}
```

Updated Values

```
   id   crime_type_id   crime_name_id    crime_suspect_id    crime_victim_id
    1               1               1                   1                  1
```

Expected output:

```
   crime_type_des      crime_name_des    crime_suspect_name    victim_name
   against property    theft              Mcdonald             Hillary
```

ReportController:

```
     public function index()
{   
   $display_crime = CrimeReport::all();


   return view('crimereports.index',compact('display_crime'));
}
```

report_table:

```
    public function up()
{
    Schema::create('crime_reports', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('crime_type_id');
        $table->string('crime_name_id');
        $table->string('suspect_id');
        $table->string('victim_id');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

//additional info

CrimeName Model

```
 public function crimeReport(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\CrimeReport');
}
```

Crime Report Model

```
 public function crimeName(){
    return $this->hasMany("App\CrimeName",'id','crime_name_id');
}
```

//Rest for CrimeReportController

```
   public function index()
{   
  $display_crime = CrimeReport::all();

  return view('crimereports.index',compact('display_crime'));


}

/**
 * Show the form for creating a new resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function create()
{   
    $display_crime_type = CrimeType::lists('crime_type','id');
    $display_crime_name = CrimeName::lists('crime_description','id');
    return view('crimereports.create',compact('display_crime_type','display_crime_name'));
}

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(CrimeNewReportRequest $request)
{
    $input = $request->all();  
    CrimeReport::create($input);

    return redirect()->back()->withSuccess("Fields were inserted!");;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your relation definition as below:

Table1 Model

```
public function list(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\ListModel');
}
```

List Model

```
public function table1(){
    return $this->belongsTo("App\Table1");
}
```

You need update your index method as below, you could dump $rows to check if this work.

ListController

```
public function index()
{   
    $res = ListModel::with(['table1','table2','table3','table4'])->get();
    $rows = [];
    $foreach($res as r) {
        $rows[] = [r->table1->name, r->table2->name, r->table3->name, r->table4->name];
    }
    dd($rows);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the response but I still get null values.

Comment: The output is undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$name;

Answer (score 0):

Your accessing table1_name on the original model change the _ to -> ( $r->table1->name)

EDIT:
Now it's starting to become much more readable. Here are what I think the relationships should be.

CrimeReport.php

```
public function crimeType()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(CrimeType::class);
}

public function crimeName()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(CrimeName::class);
}

public function suspect()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Suspect::class);
}

public function victim()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Victim::class);
}
```

There really doesn't seem to be a need to define the inverse of any of there relationships right away, if the need arises later then add them but there is no point creating the relation just because its there.

Now to make showing the report easy lets use some joins instead or eager loading.

CrimeReportController.php

```
public function index()
{
    $results = CrimeReport::query()
        ->join('crime_types as ct','ct.id', '=', 'crime_reports.crime_type_id')
        ->join('crime_names as cn','cn.id', '=', 'crime_reports.crime_name_id')
        ->join('suspects as s','s.id', '=', 'crime_reports.suspect_id')
        ->join('victims' as v','v.id', '=', 'crime_reports.victim_id')
        ->get([
            'crime_report.*', //to get ids and timestamps
            'ct.name as crime_type',
            'cn.name as crime_name',
            'suspect.name as suspent_name',
            'victim.name as victim_name'
        ])

    dd($results->toArray());
}
```

Now $results will still be a collection of CrimeReport so you can still have access to all the model goodies you might want to throw in there. In addition to that you also already have your table, you can just print these out into an html table and you have your report.

If you were wanted to add some cool search stuff to the query then you can use whereHas to do that:

```
//this would just go before the get()
$query->whereHas('suspect', function($q){
    $q->where('hair_color','=','brown')
      ->whereBetween('height',5.8,6)
})
```

Of course you might also want to make some of those leftJoins instead since I assume they won't all have a victim/suspect

Comment: Can Someone offer a solution for this. Im having hard time figuring out the problem.

Comment: Without seeing the schema for table one i cant say exactly what it should be but you definitely need to change the underscore to "->"

Comment: thanks for the response. Yeah I changed that however I get an error of Undefined property  Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$name

Comment: ok so you should be able to do $r->table1->first()->name since its a collection you will have to iterate over the results

Comment: wow it display the name..hehe. But I have a question will the first() display all the values on the List table or it will only get the first row?

Comment: It's a collection so you will need to iterate to get all the values, you can also pluck the name to get a flat array of just the names. Refer to the illuminate/support/collection class for all of the thing you can do with $row->table1 through 4

Comment: Yea using foreach right. I think you help me solved my problem.

Comment: how will I arrange from latest to oldest record. Seems ListTable::all()->latest('created_at') not working any ideas?

Comment: Can you help me out inserting those values in multiple tables and get those id's and insert in the ListTable?

Comment: I really think you should start by giving those tables more meaningful names, then using foreign keys on the list table instead of strings. Once you handle that it will be much easier to understand the structure by looking at the class names and relations. A byproduct of that is you will be able to speak with your code and everything will become more intentional rather than trial and error.

Comment: that was wonderful. Sorry if I have a lot of questions. What I want now is to get insert the victim's id and suspect's id into their own table , also I want to get that id and insert into crimereport table. Im using the insert and saving it. Do i need to use the attach method?

Comment: Just refer to the documentation on saving related models, there are many ways to save to save the related id

Comment: hello there Can you please check my code and offer some suggestions? Im done with it but Im not satisfy with my code. Thanks.

Comment: It's difficult to read through on here if you put it into a gist or something I'll take another look

Comment: okay.. This are y codes kindly check with this url..they are separated that's why you need to view in different tabs. http://codeshare.io/7n4yy      http://codeshare.io/jpCoT     http://codeshare.io/b5ytu       http://codeshare.io/f6jhj

Comment: I put it into a gist so we can work together here and see the changes https://gist.github.com/RDelorier/39db1e9d97029a04b0db

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94490/discussion-between-rdelorier-and-jay-gorio).

Comment: Thank you RDelorier.It really help me a lot.